# Create QString array of two dimensions with QVector with Qt

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, qstring, qvector

I want to to put in array some QString words but I don't know how can I do. 
I have try with Vector like this :

```
int i = 10;
int j = 10;
QVector < QVector < QString> > tableau;
QString word = "Word";
tableau[i][j] = word;
```

But that don't work.
This is the error message :

```
ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::operator[]: "index out of range"
```

Ah have try with std::vector and std::string but this don't work to

So can you explain me how to create a string array of two dimensions to put word 
Thanks

Comment: You are creating a `QVector` which has a size and capacity of 0 - you first need to fill it with elements using `append` [official reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#append)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to create a table (for which `QVector<QVector<T>>` is not the best choice) you should initialize it first.

Something like:

```
QVector<QVector<QString>> CreateTableau(int sizeX, int sizeY)
{
   QVector<QVector<QString>> result;
   for (int idx1 = 0; idx1 < sizeX; idx1++)
   {
      result.append(QVector<QString>());
      for (int idx2 = 0; idx2 < sizeY; idx2++)
      {
         result[idx1].append(QString());
      } 
   }
   return result;
}
```

then you call it like:

```
int i = 10;
int j = 10;
QVector<QVector<QString>> tableau = CreateTableau(100, 100); //TODO: replace with appropriate sizes.
QString word = "Word";
tableau[i][j] = word;
```

Comment: Someone help me and he give me this which work perfectly :                                 QVector<QVector <QString>> tableur(QVector<QVector <QString>>(10,QVector<QString>(10,"")));
    tableur[1][1] = "Mmot";
    qDebug() << tableur[1][1];